# Function Execution order when ajax included in jQuery mobile

Tags: ajax, function, jquery-mobile, execution

I got a doubt regarding the way of execution of functions having ajax calls in jQuery.

Consider two functions.

```
function auth() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: API_URL,
        data: {....
        },
        success: function (response) {}
    });
};

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: API_URL,
        data: {....
        },
        success: function (response) {}
    });
};
```

and i call these functions one after other as show below...

```
auth();
getData();
```

My situation is, I want to execute the `getData()` only after completing 'auth()' .I know we can call the `getData()` inside the success function of auth. But what i want to know is, how these functions will be executed if i call the one after another, like i shown above.

Any kind of help would be appreciated :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will execute Asynchronously. You can make them wait (Synchronous), if that is what you want, by setting **"async=false"** in the call.

```
    function auth() {
    $.ajax({
        **async: false,**
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: API_URL,
        data: {....
        },
        success: function (response) {}
    });
};

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        **aysnc: false,**
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: API_URL,
        data: {....
        },
        success: function (response) {}
    });
};
```

This will make the call finish before moving on to the next call, BUT will lock the browser usually when making the calls:

> **async** (default: true)
>   **Type**: Boolean By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. **Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.** As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

Src JQM Site: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thanks for the help buddy, thanks for the effort you've taken to draft such a detailed reply. it helped me.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**deferred objects**](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) in jQuery. Simply return the `ajax()` result.

```
function auth() {
  return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        url: API_URL,
        data: { ....  },
        success: function (response) {
        }
  });             
};

auth.done(getData);
```

This will call `getData` when `auth` is complete.

Comment: thanks for your reply :), i think this will work out. apart from this, how the functions will be excuted if i call the one after another? ie; will the second function wait for first function's ajax request to get compelted?

Comment: The second function will only execute if the first Ajax request is successful.